# How to deep filter (search) an object?

Tags: typescript, object, filter

still learning typescript over here. I have a question I need your help with.

I have the following object:

```
    public storeID: number,
    public storeName: string,
    public storeBio: string,
    public storeCoverImage: string,
    public storeLogo: string,
    public storeGallery: string[],
    public storeIsFeatured: boolean,
    public storeAmenities: string[],
    public storeContactInfo: {
      address: string;
      schedule: {
        monday: { openingHour: string; closingHour: string };
        tuesday: { openingHour: string; closingHour: string };
        wednesday: { openingHour: string; closingHour: string };
        thursday: { openingHour: string; closingHour: string };
        friday: { openingHour: string; closingHour: string };
        saturday: { openingHour: string; closingHour: string };
        sunday: { openingHour: string; closingHour: string };
      };
      email: string;
      phoneNumber: string;
      webSite: string;
      instagramProfile: string;
      facebookProfile: string;
    },
    public storeConfig: {
      allowRemoteSignup: boolean;
    },
    public userSuscriptions: [
      {
        userID: number;
        availableCredit: number;
        discounts: [
          {
            globalDiscount: number;
            itemDiscount: [
              {
                itemID: number;
                itemPrice: number;
              }
            ];
          }
        ];
      }
    ],
    public menuNotificationSuscriptions: number[],
    public eventNotificationSuscriptions: number[]
```

and I need a resulting object where `userSuscriptions.userID = 3` (which might be several records)

I've tried a filter over a filter but it does not seem to work, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in a few different ways and the best way would depend on how your is structured and what format you want the data back in.

The first way is using a filter of a filter. The inner filter looks for length, and will return true if it finds any subscriptions with ID == 3. And the outer filter returns an array of all users where the inner filter was true.

This method can also be used if you want to search the inner object on multiple ids

```
const result = this.data.filter(u => u.userSubscriptions.filter(s => s.userID === 3).length > 0);
```

Another way to go is to user array.find(), this would be used in the case where you only want to return one user with the specified ID

```
const result2 = this.data.find(u=> u.userSubscriptions.find(s=> s.userId === 3) !== undefined);
```

Also you may want to check your spelling since you spelled it Suscriptions

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I was really close, the ".length" part was missing.

Comment: I don't want to be a bother, but in this scenario, there might be other users inside my already filter by user 3, "userSubscription" array. Is there anyway to edit out those != userID 3?

I'm guessing something to do with map, right?

Comment: If i understand what you're looking for correctly. Once you have the result from the filter of a filter, you want to remove all userSubscriptions that are not equal to some value? That could be done using a map with a spread operator and a filter. But you'll need to be careful because that could effect the object in other places as objects use references, so if that is the case you'll need to deep copy the object before modifying it